# Список измененных файлов, игнорируя различия в символах перевода строк (windows/unix)

Tags: git

`git status` показывает кучу измененных файлов, в большинстве случаев имеющих различия только в символах перевода строк (windows/unix). Как среди них выявить файлы (получить списком), которые имеют и другие изменения (в тексте, пробелах, удаленные/добавленные пустые строки).

В моем случае:

windows 10 сборка 1703, git 2.6.3.windows.1

.gitattributes состоит из одной строки:

`*      -text`

Файлы в репозитарии имеют окончания LF (unix), на диске CR LF (windows).

Comment: А если так`git diff-files --name-status --ignore-space-at-eol` ?

Comment: @nick_gabpe показывает все те же файлы (не игнорирует переводы строк).

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, что вам нужна одна из этих команд

```
git diff -w | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol
git diff --ignore-space-change
git diff --ignore-all-space.
```

Попробуйте использовать их. Более детальную информацию можно получить [здесь](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: Можно как-то списком имена файлов получить, без самих diff-ов?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Конечно можно, используйте --name-only в команде.

Comment: С `--name-only` выводятся и файлы где кроме перевода строк нет изменений.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan git diff --ignore-space-change --name-only вот эта команда, показывает полный путь к файлам, в которых добавлялось, менялось, удалялось,  что-то кроме пустых пробелов и переносов строк. Если это не то, что вам нужно, пожалуйста поясните, что вам нужно

Comment: По непонятной причине у меня по этой команде выводятся файлы без изменений (кроме перевода строк). git 2.6.3.windows.1

Comment: В общем без `--name-only` можно отфильтровать, направив в `grep ^diff`, но в любом случае исключаются файлы с измененным форматированием (удалены лишние пробелы в конце строк).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan у меня гит немного новее git version 2.14.1.windows.1. И команды, которые я приводил, они тоже показывают удаленные строки и я попробовал все игноры, не один не сделал то, что нужно. Любой игнор показывает удаленные строки

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan  если найдете способ решить вашу проблему, пожалуйста поделитесь